# Rotating a 2D graph to a 3D view

Tags: graph

Any advice please as to how would I go about plotting 'by hand' a stock standard 2D sine graph 'rotated' into a 3D view like in the diagram?

[image: sine with z axis not 'sticking out of the page']

Comment: It's easy! Just add Z coordinate for all you x,y plots. Then use transform matrix for rotating.

Comment: So, if we rotate around Y, all points on graph will move around on X and Z, and movement on that plane is effectively 2D rotation, thus for Y axis rotation:
X' = X*CosA - Z*SinA
Z' = Z*CosA + x*SinA
Yes?